# Problem in Internationalization - English DLL data is always displayed

Tags: c#, dll, internationalization, culture, uiculture

I have a requirement where my UI should be shown in 5 different languages apart from English.

I have created two DLLs

1. `Component.dll`
2. `Component.resources.dll`

`Component.resources.dll` contains nothing but all the strings that are shown in the UI and a class

```cs
public class PResources
    {
        private static System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMgr = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(typeof(PEditResources));

        /// <summary>
        /// Get NLS String method string method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="identifier"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetNLSString(string identifier)
        {
            return resourceMgr.GetString(identifier, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the NLS Resource Mgr.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static System.Resources.ResourceManager GetNLSResourceMgr()
        {
            return resourceMgr;
        }
}
```

In `Component.dll` to display the label text I use the following

```
label1.text = PResources.GetNLSString("IDS_LABEL1");
```

In English it works fine...
But when the language settings is changed to French or any other, the string displayed is still the English text.

**Note:** The `Component.Resources.dll` strings are translated in all languages.

When I debugged... I found that the `GetNLSString` function the `Thread.Current.UICulture` is French ... but the `resourceMgr` object is still pointing to the English .dll path and also the `Thread.Current.Culture` is English!

Is there any solution to this ? have I missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

For every culture, you should create a folder (in the folder where the main program is) for every culture you want to support (id = two letter iso code + optional two letter region).

Inside this folder, you place the *.resources.dll, with only the strings/constants for the target culture.

Visual Studio does this automatically for you if you create an example.resx file (for the default culture) and an example.fr.resx file for French, inside the same project.

Comment: Yes, the folder are there... the respective language resource are also there .. but still it does not come up.

Comment: Oh, I thought/hoped this was an easy one. :-(